# If x = [$X$ mod $\Phi_m(X)$], why $\Phi(x) = 0$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, quotient-spaces

On https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/1481.pdf (page 3), it says:

[image]

where $\Phi_m(X)$ is the m-th cyclotomic polynomial. First of all, when we do the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(x^{4096}+1)$ for example, won't my result be the polynomials with degree maximum 4096? Why $A=\mathbb{Z}[X]$? Shouldn't it be just the polynomials with coefficient 4096 maximum?

Anyways, why $\Phi_m(x) = 0$? As far as I understood, $x$ is a polynomial, it doesn't even make sense to do $\Phi_m(x)$ technically.

Comment: Maximum degree 4095, you mean ?

Comment: @JeanMarie oops, yes

Comment: Careful with the difference between $X$ and $x$. The former seems to be an indeterminate here, whereas $x$ denotes the coset of $X$ modulo $\Phi_m(X)$ in the quotient ring $\mathcal{A}$. Then $\Bbb{Z}[x]=\mathcal{A}$ is the smallest subring of itself containing the coset $x$.

Comment: Here $\Phi_m(X)=\sum_{i=0}^Na_iX^i$ is a polynomial with coefficients $a_i\in \Bbb{Z}$. So if $R$ is **any** commutative ring, and $r\in R$, it makes sense to evaluate $\Phi_m(X)$ at $X=r$:
$$\Phi_m(r)=\sum_{i=0}^Na_ir^i.$$
When we plug in $r=x$, $\Phi_m(x)$ evaluates to be the coset of $\Phi_m(X)$, which is obviously the same coset as zero, because $\Phi_m(X)$ is in the ideal we quotient out.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what does it mean to "evaluate to be the coset of..."?